# With Angular's new HttpClient, how can I get all headers when subscribing to the events?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4.3.2 and the new [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) to download a file sent as a stream, and I need to get the headers (particularly, Content-Disposition), but they don't seem to be present in the response even though I can see the headers being correctly sent with the request in Chrome's dev tools.

This is the code:

```js
downloadDocument(documentId: number) {
    const downloadDocumentUrl = `${ this.config.apiUrls.documents }/${ documentId }`;
    const downloadRequest = new HttpRequest('GET', downloadDocumentUrl, {
        reportProgress: true,
        responseType: 'blob'
    });

    let percentageDownloaded = 0;
    this.http.request(downloadRequest).subscribe(
        (event: HttpEvent < any > ) => {
            if (event) {
                switch (event.type) {
                    case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
                        const contentDispositionHeader = event.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
                        console.log(contentDispositionHeader); // Always null here although I expected it to be there.
                        break;

                    case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
                        if (event.total) {
                            percentageDownloaded = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
                        }
                        break;

                    case HttpEventType.Response:
                        const downloadedFile: Blob = event.body;
                        fileSaverSaveAs(downloadedFile, `${ documentId }.pdf`, true); // This is where I'd like to use content-disposition to use the actual file name.
                        break;
                }
            }
         ,
        (err) => {}
    );
}
```

When this code gets called, Chrome reports in the network tab of dev tools the following response headers:

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=doc5619362.pdf; filename*=UTF-8''doc5619362.pdf
Content-Length:88379
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Thu, 03 Aug 2017 09:43:41 GMT
Server:Kestrel
Vary:Origin
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

Any ideas on how I can access all the headers present in the response? It is not just Content-Disposition that is not present, all of the other headers are not there except for Content-Type.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is a working Plunker demonstrating the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/UXZuhWYKHrqZCZkUapgC?p=preview

Comment: `event.headers.get(...)` is the correct approach

Comment: As Maximus recommend; doc: https://angular.io/api/http/Response#headers

Comment: @ManhLe This link is for the old `Http` docs, the OP is using the new `HttpClient`, therefor the right link to the docs would be: [DOCS](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Maximus, as you can see in my example code that is the approach I am taking but it is not working, the headers are not there.

Comment: so it means the problem is somewhere else, can you setup a plunker?

Comment: Plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/UXZuhWYKHrqZCZkUapgC?p=preview

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is not Angular, is the CORS handshaking:
If the server does not explicitly allow your code to read the headers, the browser will hide them from it. The server must add in its responses the header `Access-Control-Expose-Headers:<header_name>,<header-name2>` in order to let you to read them, but currently it only allows to do a request and to read the response's body by adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Pablo. Unfortunately, on my real scenario CORS is allowed just fine and the file downloads just fine, but still no headers. I should be still getting headers though, in that Plunkr. I could not find a file to point to that would allow CORS for the example.

Comment: Are you sure?I mean then the plunkr scenario is not a valid one, that header is not present there so any other problem cannot be reproduced there

Comment: I've updated the plunkr to a request that allows CORS: https://plnkr.co/edit/UXZuhWYKHrqZCZkUapgC?p=preview

Comment: As I said, your plunkr allows CORS (access-control-allow-origin), but the header to allow other headers (Access-Control-Expose-Headers) is not present

Comment: Would the headers show up in the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools if CORS wasn't allowing them through?

Comment: Yes, they would, because they are sent by the server. But Chrome would hide them from your code due to CORS restrictions (the server must explicitly expose them)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will investigate this. My backend code is using ASP.NET Core and my policy is built with "AllowAnyHeader", so in theory, they should be available, but I'll look further into it and will try it without CORS as well, thanks.

Comment: Allow any header (request headers are accepted) is something totally different from "Expose any header" (response headers can be read by anyone)