# Angular 4 new HttpClient content-disposition header

Tags: angular, blob, httpclient

I am trying to get a file (array buffer) from my backend using the new HttpClient.

My code is pretty much like the following:

```
this.http.post(url, body, {responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
    console.log(resp.headers.get('content-disposition'));
  });
```

The repsonse in my browser console is *null*

When I take a look at the network tab, then I see that content-disposition has a value like *attachment; filename="whatever"*

If I try to get *content-type* instead, then I receive something.

Have you experienced something similar or can you tell me what I have to do else?
Many thanks

Comment: there is a relation to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389488/angular-4-3-httpclient-empty-response-headers but I could not solve it yet

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I had the same Issue and found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45482346/1909698

It worked for me after adding `'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition'` in my backend response header.

Comment: That was exactly what I searched for.  Solved my problem. Thank you =)

Comment: Thanks! This was also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897764/asp-net-core-content-disposition-attachment-inline

Comment: Thanks great find, the issue is so misleading because in browser you see the content-disposition but angular does not see it until you tell the server specifically to expose the specific header.

Comment: I didn't need 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition' in Angular 12 (anymore?!)

Answer (score 0):

if your backend is using `SpringSecurity` you need add `ExposeHeader` to *configuration source*:

```
@Bean
protected CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.addExposedHeader("Content-Disposition");
    return source;
}
```